# Sending notifications to a android phone via a web service

Tags: android, web-services, notifications

I have an android application which collect accelerometer and microphone data. If those data satisfy a predefined condition, they should sends to a web service. Then all other android phones which a connected with this web service(phones which have the same application) can be received a notification automatically. But I have no idea about this notification sending part. What is the way to send notification to connected phones automatically.
Thank you....!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use push technology. You are in luck, there is C2DM(cloud to device Messaging) for android. Start from this blog

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html

Answer (score 2):

You could go through this tutorial too,its a nice and neat one

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

Answer (score 2):

Was looking for this today, finished using :

http://www.pushbullet.com/ + Looked at : https://github.com/rharder/jpushbullet2